# Wordpress Menu with ::after CSS Styling

Tags: css

I want to add the | pipe to the end of each li tag excluding the first and last. is there a better way to do this, was thinking maybe using `:nth-child()` selector?

```
 .categoryMenu ul li::after {
         content: ' | ';
    }

.categoryMenu ul li:nth-child(1) {
     content: 'hello';
     background: red;
}
```

seems that the content css property does not work with `:nth-child()` only `::after`

Comment: li:nth-child(1):after. The red background color will be appended to content not to li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a border instead of a pipe?
Something like:

```
.categoryMenu ul li {
    padding: 0 1em;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
}
.categoryMenu ul li:first-child {
    border-left:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
.categoryMenu ul li:after {
  content: ' | ';
}

.categoryMenu ul li:first-child:after, .categoryMenu ul li:last-child:after {
  content: '';
}
```

Seems like the browser support for these selectors are good now,
[Can I Use: CSS3 Selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

Answer (score 0):

You can also you `first-child` and `last-child` selectors which would perfectly work in your case with `li` in `ul`.

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/anodw24a/), where first and last elements have no pipe at the end of them.